# Difference in size between std::vector and std::deque

Tags: c++, vector, stl, size, deque

Right after I declare a `vector<int>` and a `deque<int>` if I print out `sizeof` on both of them, the `std::vector` has 12 bytes ( I guess begin, end and size ) while `deque` has 40 bytes. Where do those extra bytes come from?

I'm using `Code::Blocks IDE 13.12` and I did select the `C++11` standard to be used.

Comment: Why not take a peek inside your compiler's `<deque>` header and find out?

Comment: Hmmm...:  http://ideone.com/LBYvnG

Comment: Sorry, simplified by 4 for some reason.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because the contents of many implementation's `std` headers are abominations that no mortal should be forced to read.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm trying to look at the implementation but I can't realise the difference :(

Comment: @user1640736, If you're question is "How does my compiler implement std::deque?", you've not provided enough information.

Answer (score 2):

The size is implementation dependent; but it's not surprising that the control structure for a more complicated structure like `deque` might be larger than a simple one like `vector` (which, as you say, can be easily managed by three pointers, or a pointer and two sizes).

Looking at the GNU implementation, it stores precalculated "start" and "end" iterators, presumably because they're difficult to calculate on demand, and easier to update when the container changes. Each of those is quite complicated, containing four pointers: the current position, the start and end of the current block, and a pointer to a map structure needed to move between blocks. The `deque` also has a (possibly redundant?) pointer to that map, and the size (again, presumably difficult to calculate on demand), giving a total of ten pointers/sizes, as you observed.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator takes the size of the *object* and not the size of its contents.

So if an object have three data member variables, the `sizeof` operator will get the size of those member variables, but if one of them is a pointer to more data then you only get the size of the pointer and not the length of the data it points to.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Why is the sizeof a vector 3 bytes and the sizeof a deque 10 bytes?

Comment: @user1640736 The internal data of the container objects is up to the *implementation*, the C++ specification does not say anything about member variables, only how the classes should *behave*.

Comment: I tried looking at the documentation, trying to look at the implementation at this moment but I barely understand a thing ...

Comment: @user1640736 ***Don't*** look at the implementation, only read documentation (like [this reference of the C++ containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)). The implementation is not really meant to be looked at, besides it will differ between different standard library implementation. It will also be very complex and not meant to be used as a reference (use a [proper reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)).

Answer (score 0):

sizeof does not give you the number of elements in a container; rather the compile time evaluated size of the structure.

So the actual value is down to the implementation of the standard library and, as such, can vary from platform to platform.